# Loop with predict raster function in R

Tags: raster, r, loop

My data is a dataframe of ALTITUDE in the first column, and monthly temperatures (let's say for a year) in the other columns. I used the following code to create a linear model for each monthly temperature as the response variable and altitude as the explanatory variable.

```
y <- names(data) 
models <- lapply(y, function(x) {
  lm(substitute(i~ALTITUDE, list(i = as.name(x))), data = data)})
```

Therefore, I got 12 models to predict temperature based on altitude. Then I read my raster file, which was a DEM, and changed its name to use predict function later.

```
raster <- raster("Data/raster/DEM.tif") 
names(raster) <- c("ALTITUDE")
```

I took one model from the 12 created to perform predict function, like this:

```
model1 <-(models[[1]]) 
rastert <- predict(raster, model1)
```

So, the values of altitude from the DEM (raster variable), were taken and used on the model1 to create a rastert which is the temperature stimated raster.

Now, I want to perform the predict function like this for the 12 models at once. 
I was trying to use the following for loop, but it is not working. I am new using geodata on R. Can someone suggest a link to check out about looping with rasters?

```
rastert <- NULL

for(i in models){
  rastert[[i]] <- predict(raster,i) 
}
```

Comment: I tried making a data frame that agrees with what you said (ALTITUDE in first column plus some other columns with names you don't specify) `data = data.frame(ALTITUDE=runif(10), t1=runif(10), t2=runif(10), t3=runif(10), t4=runif(10))` but your first line of code fails. Can you make a reproducible example?

Comment: I think you mean to do `y = names(data)[-1]` so you don't try modelling `ALTITUDE~ALTITUDE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
for(i in models){
  rastert[[i]] <- predict(raster,i) 
}
```

isn't going to work because you are trying to use `i` as a model (in `predict`) and as a list index (in `rastert[[i]]`).

To fix that, loop over the *indexes* (here `i` is 1 to the number of models) and extract the model you want inside the loop:

```
 for(i in seq_along(models)){print(i);rastert[[i]]=predict(raster,models[[i]])}
```

Its also failing because you start `rastert` as a `NULL` and then try adding complex objects to it like its a list:

```
> rastert=NULL
> rastert[[1]]=predict(raster,models[[1]])
Error in rastert[[1]] = predict(raster, models[[1]]) : 
  invalid type/length (S4/0) in vector allocation
```

to fix that, initialise it as an empty list:

```
> rastert=list()
> rastert[[1]]=predict(raster,models[[1]])
```

Now we can add one element to the object, we can do the lot:

```
> rastert=list()
> for(i in seq_along(models)){rastert[[i]]=predict(raster,models[[i]])}
>
```

and do a little sanity checking - is the second thing in the list what I get when I do it "by hand"?

```
> identical(rastert[[2]], predict(raster, models[[2]]))
[1] TRUE
```

Yes. Good.

You can then also do it using `lapply`, since you don't really need the indexes:

```
> rastert2 = lapply(models, function(m){predict(raster, m)})
```

`lapply` returns a list without you needing to initialise it. Again, quick sanity check comparing with the previous:

```
> identical(rastert2[[2]], rastert[[2]])
[1] TRUE
```